# Alloy Analyzer element comparision from set

Tags: alloy, formal-verification

Some background: my project is to make a compiler that compiles from a c-like language to Alloy. The input language, that has c-like syntax, must support **contracts**. For now, I am trying to implement if statements that support **pre** and **post** **condition** statements, similar to the following:

```
int x=2
if_preCondition(x>0)
if(x == 2){
   x = x + 1
}
if_postCondtion(x>0)
```

The problem is that I am a bit confused with the results of Alloy.

```
sig  Number{
    arg1: Int,
}

fun addOneConditional (x : Int) : Number{
    { v : Number | 
            v.arg1 = ((x = 2 ) => x.add[1] else x)
    }
}

assert conditionalSome {
    all n: Number|  (n.arg1 = 2 ) => (some field: addOneConditional[n.arg1] | { field.arg1 = n.arg1.add[1] }) 
}

assert conditionalAll {
    all n: Number|  (n.arg1 = 2 ) => (all field: addOneConditional[n.arg1] | { field.arg1 = n.arg1.add[1] }) 
}

check conditionalSome
check conditionalAll
```

In the above example, `conditionalAll` does not generate any `Counterexample`. However, `conditionalSome`generates `Counterexamples`. If I understand `all` and `some` quantifiers correctly then there is a mistake. Because from mathematical logic we have ***Ɐx expr(x) => ∃x expr(x)*** ( i.e. *If expression expr(x) is true for all values of x then there exist a single x for which expr(x) is true*)

Comment: I am lost what you're trying to do here, even after editing your problem because it was hard to read lacking any formatting. Could you reduce the problem to the minimum? I.e. you've got problems it helps to reduce to the absolute min. One hint, do not use Int. There are some significant handicaps with Ints that you want to avoid when learning alloy. Try to create a small problem that shows your problem without reverting to Int.

Comment: Than you for your time. I edited the question, hopefully it is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing is that you need to *model* your pre-, post- and operations. Functions are terrible for that because they cannot *not* return something that indicates failure. You, therefore, need to model the operation as a *predicate*. The value of a predicate indicates if the pre/post are satisfied, the arguments and return values can be modeled as parameters.

This is as far as I can understand your operation:

```
pred add[ x : Int, x' : Int ] {
  x > 0             -- pre condition
  x = 2 => 
    x'=x.plus[1] 
  else 
    x'=x
  x' > 0            -- post condition
}
```

Alloy has no writable variables (Electrum has) so you need to model the before and after state with a *prime* (') character.

We can now use this predicate to calculate the set of *solutions* to your problem:

```
fun solutions : set Int {
  { x' : Int | some x : Int | add[ x,x' ] }
}
```

We create a set with integers for which we have a *result*. The prime character is nothing special in Alloy, it is only a convention for the post-state. I am abusing it slightly here.

This is more than enough Alloy source to make mistakes so let's test this.

```
run { some solutions }
```

If you run this then you'll see in the `Txt` view:

```
skolem $solutions={1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
```

This is as expected. The `add` operation only works for positive numbers. *Check*. If the input is 2, the result is 3. Ergo, 2 can never be a solution. *Check*.

I admit, I am slight confused by what you're doing in your asserts. I've tried to replicate them faithfully, although I've removed unnecessary things, at least I think we're unnecessary. First your `some` case. Your code was doing an `all` but then selecting on 2. So removed the outer quantification and hardcoded 2.

```
check  somen {
    some x' : solutions | 2.plus[1] = x'
}
```

This indeed does not give us any counterexample. Since `solutions` was `{1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}`, 2+1=3 is in the set, i.e. the `some` condition is satisfied.

```
check  alln {
    all x' : solutions  | 2.plus[1] = x'
}
```

However, not all solutions have 3 as the answer. If you check this, I get the following counter-example:

```
skolem $alln_x'={7}
skolem $solutions={1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
```

*Conclusion*. Daniel Jackson advises not to learn Alloy with Ints. Looking at your Number class you took him literally: you still base your problem on Ints. What he meant is not use Int, don't hide them under the carpet in a field. I understand where Daniel is coming from but Ints are very attractive since we're so familiar with them. However, if you use Ints, let them at least use their full glory and don't hide them.

Hope this helps.

And the whole model:

```
pred add[ x : Int, x' : Int ] {
    x > 0               -- pre condition
    x = 2 => 
        x'=x.plus[1] 
    else 
        x'=x
    x' > 0              -- post condition
}   
fun solutions : set Int { { x' : Int | some x : Int | add[ x,x' ] } }

run { some solutions }
check  somen { some x' : solutions | x' = 3 }   
check  alln { all x' : solutions  | x' = 3 }
```

Comment: Than you for your time and detailed explanation. I have an additional question. I would like to create an assert that checks the  `pred add` (i.e. translated **if** statement) holds (is true) for all possible values of `int x` (of course the domain of x is restricted ). Meaning, it tests that when the pre condition of the **if** statement holds then the post condition of the **if** statement  holds.
Would the following assertion work ?
`check postCondition{
  { all x : Int | some x' : Int | (x>0) => add[ x,x' ] } 
}`

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Yes. I tried some test cases and it seems to do what I expected it to do. I just wanted to make sure that I am not misunderstanding something given that I am very new to the software verification world and Alloy.